# Performing Power Operations in Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
 dict1 = {'A': 2,'B': 4,'C': 6}
```

I want a new dictionary to be the values of dict1 squared.

```
 dict2 = {'A': 4,'B': 16,'C': 36}
```

A tried using

```
for k in dict1.keys():
    value = dict[k]
    for k1 in value.keys():
        value[k1] =  value**2     # also tried pow(value,2.)
```

The error I get is AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `value` is not a dictionary so the `keys()` method doesn't work.

Comment: Just a heads-up: If you call `.keys()` on a dict you are usually doing something wrong (iterating a dict already gives you its keys, no need to copy them to a list first). Also, if you use `somedict[key]` inside such a look it means you actually wanted to iterate over `key, value` tuples using `iteritems()` (`items()` in Python 3) instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to create `dict2`:

```
dict2 = {}
```

Then, you can populate it using the keys and values of `dict1`:

```
for key in dict1.keys():
    dict2[key] = dict1[key] ** 2
```

Or in one line:

```
dict2 = {key: value ** 2 for key, value in dict1.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful answer.

Comment: I think it'd be wise to avoid using `.keys()` here. It's not needed (actually, it's a good case for `items()`/`iteritems()`)

Answer (score 3):

You can just iterate through your old dictionary using a dictionary comprehension like so (python 2):

```
>>> dict1 = {'A': 2,'B': 4,'C': 6}
>>> dict2 = {k:v**2 for k,v in dict1.iteritems()}
>>> dict2
{'A': 4, 'C': 36, 'B': 16}
```

Note that for python 3:

```
>>> dict2 = {k:v**2 for k,v in dict1.iteritems()}
```

becomes

```
>>> dict2 = {k:v**2 for k,v in dict1.items()}
```